# How to run Eclipse memory analyzer on Mac os?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have some issues with running Eclipse memory analyzer on my laptop.

This happen when i have just downloaded(from [the place](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php)) and executed application:

[image]

[image]

And i can't figure out what is the cause of problem. Can someone help me???

Answer (score 69):

Move mat.app to `./Applications` solve my problems

Comment: And also a funny one :)

Comment: Tried different solutions like adding -data but this is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

This is a bug, you can run command:

```
1. cd mat.app/Contents/MacOS
2. ./MemoryAnalyzer
```

Comment: Apparently still a bug

Comment: it works on my M1 pro, using  MemoryAnalyzer-1.14.0.20230315-macosx.cocoa.x86_64.dmg

Answer (score 9):

It looks like a permission problem with the default directory.

From this discussion : [Memory Analyzer » Setting up workspace directory?](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/214452/).

It is indicated that you should edit your ***MemoryAnalyzer.ini*** file, and add those lines (**on two separate lines, and before the vm arguments**), replacing the second with the path where you want the MemoryAnalyzer to write its content:

```
-data
<desired path of your working directory>
```

Comment: This worked for me because I have corporate nanny-ware installed that prevents me from altering ini files, Info.plist, etc.  

So:   
1. download and install https://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php   
2. mkdir ~/.mat   
3. cd /Applications/mat.app/Contents/MacOS   
4. ./MemoryAnalyzer -data ~/.mat.

Answer (score 2):

- Find the `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` file .
- Add the following content:

```
-vm
<your Java1.7 path>
```

Comment: or path to the 'java' executable from an installed JDK8

Comment: On MacOS, it worked for me when I add the java path with `/bin` suffix

Comment: This didn't work for me, but `export JAVA_HOME="/Users/matschaffer/.asdf/installs/java/oracle-17"; open /Applications/mat.app` did.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution is to

```
open mat.app --args -data ~/<your-folder>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the latest [Eclipse Memory Analyzer snapshot build](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/mat/snapshots/rcp/org.eclipse.mat.ui.rcp.MemoryAnalyzer-macosx.cocoa.x86_64.dmg) work better for you? This is a signed and notarized dmg not a zip so might be easier to install.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issue running MAT(Eclipse memory analyzer) on Mac. So I have tried installing "Eclipse Memory Analyzer" plugin in Sts that I use, it worked.

**You can also install MAT as plugin in Eclipse/STS that you use already.**

Answer (score 0):

adding a quick reference for people using sdkman,

$JAVA_HOME is set to

```
/Users/{yourusername}/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/
```

now modify the startup config for the program

```
nano /Applications/MemoryAnalyzer.app/Contents/Eclipse/MemoryAnalyzer.ini
```

add the following two separate lines before any vmargs

```
-vm
<the-value-of-your-java-home>/bin
```