# Unable to run eclipse MAT in MAC

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-memory-analyzer, eclipse-mat

[Link of error message that pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auJnY.png) when I am installing Eclipse MAT from http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php

I want to analyse heap dumps but stuck at installation. Can someone help?

[log messages when we install MAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCYig.png)

Comment: I simply droped the .app file into Mac's Application folder.

Answer (score 2):

Solution that worked for me:
Move mat.app to ./Applications

Credits to : [How to run Eclipse memory analyzer on Mac os?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909239/how-to-run-eclipse-memory-analyzer-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 1):

1. find MemoryAnalyzer.ini file
2. add below data property in it. Note that this must be added before the vm parameters, if any.

   `-data
   /Users/*/logs/mat`
3. Reference: [how to change the Memory Analyzer workspace directory](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/214452/)